# Regex to Get String Ending with the First Occurrence Either of Two Kinds of Character(s)

Tags: regex

I have been struggling coming up with a regex to extract string ending with the first occurrence of either "]" or " -" (space hyphen). The tricky part is that in one log line, these 2 can show up multiple times with no guarantee of a sequence.

The sample log lines are like below

```
2018-01-01 01:25:13,000 [Component (wokflow) thread#12 - function[queue]] WARNING - some log
2018-01-01 01:26:15,000 [MQ session task-156] INFO - some other log
```

What I want to extract is "Component (wokflow) thread#12" and "MQ session task-156".

The pattern definitely starts with a "[", but ends with either "]" or " -", whichever comes first.

Comment: What environment are you running your regex in? I'd propose a lazy quantifier + a lookahead, but those features aren't implemented by every regex engine.

Comment: Should not the 2nd output supposed to be `MQ session task` ? because - comes first

Comment: Also, what language are you trying this with?

Comment: If it is PCRE, try [`^.*?\[\K.*?(?= -|])`](https://regex101.com/r/9oBQ4q/1). Else, [`^.*?\[(.*?)(?= -|])`](https://regex101.com/r/9oBQ4q/2) and grab Group 1.

Comment: Well, if you can use capture groups and your tool or programming language supports lookaheads then you could try with something like `^.*?\[(.*?)(?=\s*[\[\]-])`. Or in the case of the PCRE engine use the `\K` f.e. `^.*?\[\K(.*?)(?=\s*[\[\]-])`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, after posting this, I kind of figured it out. Something like below should work, I think

```
\[(((?! -|\]).)+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this perl solution.

```
> cat regex_start_end.dat
2018-01-01 01:25:13,000 [Component (wokflow) thread#12 - function[queue]] WARNING - some log
2018-01-01 01:26:15,000 [MQ session task-156] INFO - some other log
> perl -pe  ' s/(.+?)\[(.+?)( -|\])(.*)/\2/g ;  ' regex_start_end.dat
Component (wokflow) thread#12
MQ session task-156
>
```

Can you provide some more samples